# What is rotating?

Tags: terminology, counter-strike-global-offensive

I've barely scratched the surface of competitive CS:GO, but from what I've heard, the phrase "rotating" is shouted out a lot.

What exactly do players mean when they say "rotating".  Does this mean players on another team are swapping roles? Or does it mean that they're moving from one Bombsite/Hostage to another?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's a common term that means something to the effect of "getting into a different position to attack from another angle". I'm not at all confident enough to post that as an answer though.

Comment: Generally CT's are the ones doing the rotation. For example, if the bomb and all of the Terrorists are seen trying to push a site, players who are defending the other site will need to rotate. Or perhaps only a few enemies will be spotted, and not the bomb, so not all of the CT's will rotate immediately.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Rotating is effectively moving between points of interest on the map - this could be bomb sites, hostage locations, locations where a team mate just died, or other mission objective.

It's not specific to Counter Strike. Use the following map of de_dust2 as an example;

[image]

While the routes may not be exact, rotating on this map would generally indicate moving between the bomb sites marked with red X's.

Answer (score 4):

I have no experience of Counter Strike competitive, but I have watched matches. So, for example you're a terrorist.

You're in Bomb Site A with the bomb, and someone from the enemy team spots you heading there. You will need to "rotate" to Bomb Site B since you'll get killed in A. Basically, it is going to another place in the map from where you are.

Comment: What an incredibly obtuse term.

Comment: @kotekzot Makes sense to me, but maybe only because I've heard it used so much. Any better ideas?